# Can ceremonial casting be applied to formulaic magic?

Tags: ars-magica-5

The description of Ceremonial Casting on p. 83 says:

> A maga may spend fifteen minutes for every magnitude of the spell performing rituals to invoke the powers of natural magic. As a result, she may add her scores in Artes Liberales and Philosophiae to her casting score. A maga
>   may use ceremonial casting even if she has no experience points in one of the two Abilities, but not if she has no experience points in either.

Can this be applied to formulaic magic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not by default - on the same page, just after the large header that reads "Spontaneous Casting" is the paragraph that begins: "The following options can only be used when a maga is using Spontaneous magic".

Ceremonial casting is one of the options under that header, and as such cannot be used with Formulaic casting.

There are however additional options which can apply Ceremonial Casting to Formulaic spells but they are limited special cases - Two examples of these are:

- Hermetic Geometry (a Minor Mystery Virtue found on page 93 of The Mysteries Revised Edition) which allows you to directly use the Ceremonial Casting rules even for Formulaic spells as long as the spell in question involves a regular geometric figure
- Ceremonial Casting mastery ability (a mastery ability known to the Cult of Mercury and found on page 99 of Houses of Hermes: True Lineages which, assuming you have access to it, you can select from when increasing a Formulaic spell's mastery level) which allows you to use Ceremonial Casting on that specific mastered spell.